# how to write SQL script that handles two posible date formats inside a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL scripts that is trying to convert

```
SET @FRecepcion = CONVERT(
          VARCHAR(30),CAST(@FechaRecepcion AS DATETIME),107
      )+ ' ' +
      CONVERT(
          VARCHAR(30),CAST(@FechaRecepcion AS DATETIME),108
      )
 IF (@FRecepcion = NULL)
 BEGIN
    SET @FRecepcion = ''
 END
```

When @FechaRecepcion is arriving with the expected format `Aug 30, 2013 20:10:44` the conversion works.

But when testing this script in other computers @FechaRecepcion arrives like this   `2013-08-30 20:10:44.000` and the conversion fails

How can I write a SQL logic that can handle both cases ? or what is the best aproach to solve this ?

Comment: Is the time genuinely `24:12:00.000` or is it `00:12:00.000`?  If `24`, that's the problem.

Comment: What is the error message that is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me after I updated the example date `2013-08-30 24:12:00.000` to `2013-08-30 00:12:00.000` the query you provided works.  I verified on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19778).  `24` is not a valid hour for a DATETIME.  It should probably be `00` (and maybe the day part of the date incremented by 1).

You need to find out why some computers are returning 24 for the hour instead of a valid hour. Depending on why the hour part is set that way, you could possibly parse the input string and then update the date as needed.

**Example with *expected* date format** (Aug 30, 2013 20:10:44):

```
SET @FechaRecepcion = 'Aug 30, 2013 20:10:44'  -- setup test data

SET @FRecepcion = CONVERT(
          VARCHAR(30),CAST(@FechaRecepcion AS DATETIME),107
      )+ ' ' +
      CONVERT(
          VARCHAR(30),CAST(@FechaRecepcion AS DATETIME),108
      )
```

**Example with *unexpected* date format** (2013-08-30 20:10:44.000), but using the same script to parse date value:

```
SET @FechaRecepcion = '2013-08-30 20:10:44.000'  -- setup test data

SET @FRecepcion = CONVERT(
          VARCHAR(30),CAST(@FechaRecepcion AS DATETIME),107
      )+ ' ' +
      CONVERT(
          VARCHAR(30),CAST(@FechaRecepcion AS DATETIME),108
      )
```

EDIT: Updated example query to match the example that was provided in the original question.

Comment: Adam..sorry about the 24 as hour, it was a mistake. Does your code works as a single SCRIPT for both formats ?

Comment: Yes, when I tried it with both formats, it worked. I updated the example I provided so that it matches the script in your question.

Comment: Adams, thanks but I would like to understand how does this work given that format 107 is "mon dd, yyyy" and 108 if "hh:mm:ss" for the second format does not match that format since is in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm" ?

Comment: The SQL you provided casts @FechaRecepcion to a DATETIME first. So the CONVERT function is now working on a DATETIME value and converts to the 107 format which is "mon dd, yyyy". It doesn't know what the original format of the input string was, Then CONVERT function is called again to get the time format "hh:mm:ss.mmm" using the 108 format code. 

The resulting output is always in the format "mon dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss.mmm" regardless of what the original string format is, as long as the format is a date-time format that SQL Server recognizes.